# Window resize. Adapt width conditionals

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that is shorter when a button appears. I think it works well in the example I provide. The problem comes when the user change the size of the window. I suppose I should use the resize function. In fact, it works as I want when the button is not visible. But I do not know how to use the resize and the ability to appear and disappear the button at the same time.

(I know that it would be easy with flex or calc but I need to work with older browsers)

```js
// at the beginning:
var centerWidth1 = $('#wrap').width();
var centerWidth2 = $('#wrap').width() - 55; /*50+5*/
$(".center").css('width', centerWidth1);

// when I move the window: (it does not work)
$(window).resize(function() {
  //centerWidth3 = $('#wrap').width();
  //$(".center").css('width', centerWidth3);
});

// make the button appear
$(".center").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).animate({
    width: centerWidth2
  }, 400);
  
  $('.center').not(this).animate({
    width: centerWidth1
  }, 400);

  $(this).siblings(".right").delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
  $('.center').not(this).siblings(".right").fadeOut(0);
});

// click outside
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.right').fadeOut(200);
  $('.center').delay(200).animate({
    width: centerWidth1
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have been working on this for many hours and I have make an intensive search. If you want me to close this question, please tell me why and what else should I do to improve or change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do a couple changes, but I think it should work as expected now. I didn't change anything in the button click handler. Let me know if you have questions.

```
// Define the global variables, so we can reuse them in functions
var centerWidth1;
var centerWidth2;

// Get the wrap and save in variable, so it doesn't get fetched on each resize event
var wrap = $('#wrap')

// call the function on pageload AND on resize
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  centerWidth1 = wrap.width();
  centerWidth2 = wrap.width() - 55; /*50+5*/

  // jQuery's .css supports functions, so we can set different widths when the window is resized and the button is visible
  $(".center").css('width', function(){
    if ($(this).siblings('.right').css('display') === 'block') {
      return centerWidth2
    } else {
      return centerWidth1
    }
  });
});

$(window).trigger('resize'); // if you call this inside a load event, you may need to trigger the resize event so the function is called immediately


/* --------- didn't change the rest down here ---------- */
// make the button appear
$(".center").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).animate({
    width: centerWidth2
  }, 400);

  $('.center').not(this).animate({
    width: centerWidth1
  }, 400);

  $(this).siblings(".right").delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
  $('.center').not(this).siblings(".right").fadeOut(0);
});

// click outside
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.right').fadeOut(200);
  $('.center').delay(200).animate({
    width: centerWidth1
  }, 400);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/burx60dn/4/

Comment: I copy-paste your code in my local file and it does not work. I tried many things and I cannot make it work. I see that it works in jsfiddle so I do not understand. Any guess what could it be?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are there console errors and do you have other JS that might interfere? (something onload or resize)

Comment: The problem is that it does not work on load but it works on resize. To test it I try jsbin (a tool that is similar to jsfiddle but it lets us put all the code of the page) https://jsbin.com/maducagufo/edit?html,output  This is how I see it in my local file too

Comment: @Nrc Try adding `$(window).trigger('resize');` after the `load resize` function (see updated code in question). The problem is that you wrapped it all in `$(function(){` which is shorthand for a load event. So in the load event you set a new load event, but of course the load event was already fired, so it doesn't do anything.